# POST multiple values in jquery especially if names are the same

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a table(NOT FORM), in php which I generated in a while  loop. 
one of the inputs is generated 20 input, with or without any data in it. I am trying to run an update/save using jquery and I need to post all the values in that input.

This is in a while loop. It is basically loops and render the data from the table into the image you can see below. If you count the input box in the image, it is 20.

[webpage layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wUFi3.png)

```
echo '<input type="text" name="access[' . $count . '][' . $a . ']" id="access[' . $ucount . '][' . $a . ']" size="1" maxlength="2" value="' . $user_access[$a] . '" />';
```

In a html page you will see this

```
<input type="text" value="RO" maxlength="2" size="1" id="access[2][0]" name="access[2][0]">
<input type="text" value="SQ" maxlength="2" size="1" id="access[2][1]" name="access[2][1]">
and without ant data it will be the `value` will be blank.
<input type="text" value="" maxlength="2" size="1" id="access[2][2]" name="access[2][2]">
```

Now because I am using jQuery ajax to do an `update` / `save`. How will I sent everything in all 20 input boxes via jQuery?
I have done a normal and this is how I normally do it below.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('[name="save_record"]').unbind('click').click(function () {

        var update_user = $(this).parent().parent().find('[name="user"]').val();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST';

            url: 'update.php';

            data: {

                update_user: update_user
            },
            success: function (Response) {

                alert(Response);
            })
        });
    });
```

but I know for this method of post all values in all 20 input boxes will be different but I have try it like i did above and it only post the first value in the first input box.

**question**
  How can I post values in all 20 input boxes? please based your answer/ example as if you the input boxes where empty as first.

*NOTE*
  some values may be empty so i need to also check that none of the input boxes are null.

Thanks

Comment: `$('input[name^="access"]').each(function(){ });` and create an array of values and send as JSON or something.

Comment: @putvande thanks. Need to look up some Jquery array. Never used it before. Only been using Jquery for about 2 months now. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$.post(
    '/my-url',
    {
        data: $('#my-form').serialize()
    },
    function (data) {
        // some processing successful result here
    }
);
```

Using `<input>` tags without `<form>` is impropriety

Comment: Yes and NO because you can use `parent` and child with will ref to everything in that row... in that question above, I have use the same jquery in that question to save and delete  data in my table... using jquery `this` and parent. It doesn't always have to be in a form